# reprojectImageTo3D() in OpenCV and point cloud 3d modelling

Tags: c++, opencv, point-cloud-library, 3d-modelling

! I'm doing some work on 3d modelling with opencv and point cloud library. 
I have done a lot of research and came to know that after cameraCalibration -> use stereorectification then -> reprojectImageto3d -> show results in 3d viewer with PointCloud.

Since I've done all the steps but I couldn't make it to the results I really wanted. The problem I'm facing is after stereorectification the initUndistortrectifymap and remap gives me very bad results like only a type of 3 lines and because of these the 3d view result is very bad. 
Anyone here please help me cause I had such a short time to complete this work.
P.S.
I can't be able to attach any picture of my result here Cause I'm new and I heard that I've to make 50+ reputations etc. 
I'm posting my code may be that will help you. 
below is the code I'm using.

```
  Mat imgLeft = imread("trible.jpg", 0);
    Mat imgRight = imread("trible1.JPG", 0);

    cv::Mat_<double> CameraMatrix1(3, 3);
    cv::Mat_<double> CameraMatrix2(3, 3);
    cv::Mat_<double> disCoeffs1(8, 1);
    cv::Mat_<double> disCoeffs2(8, 1);
    cv::Mat_<double> R(3,3);
    cv::Mat_<double> T(3, 1);

    CameraMatrix1 << 3.7418800905573778e+002, 0, 2.8292646601205792e+002, 0,
        3.7418800905573778e+002, 1.9600567927223364e+002, 0, 0, 1;
    CameraMatrix2 << 3.7418800905573778e+002, 0, 1.9738001176691122e+002, 0,
        3.7418800905573778e+002, 1.9213950093058386e+002, 0, 0, 1;
    disCoeffs1 << 8.4846284211974010e-001, -6.8586657466127905e+000, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, -2.1939018609332440e+001;
    disCoeffs2 << -1.0450215273644869e+000, 5.6341039084121618e+001, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 2.5604871618687031e+002;
    R << 9.9004326094229356e-001, -3.0104115731476408e-002,
        -1.3750666776115050e-001, 4.9787774041489000e-002,
        9.8860863120095721e-001, 1.4203574152643209e-001,
        1.3166441819543800e-001, -1.4746767961487581e-001,
        9.8026412994165057e-001;
    T << 3.6832840828600544e+000, -1.3250441137852145e+000,
        3.1984415574963926e-001;

    cv::Mat R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
    cv::stereoRectify(CameraMatrix1, disCoeffs1, CameraMatrix2, disCoeffs2, imgLeft.size(), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, 0, 0, imgLeft.size(),0,0);

    double Q03, Q13, Q23, Q32, Q33;
    Q03 = Q.at<double>(0, 3);
    Q13 = Q.at<double>(1, 3);
    Q23 = Q.at<double>(2, 3);
    Q32 = Q.at<double>(3, 2);
    Q33 = Q.at<double>(3, 3);

    std::cout << "Q(0,3) = " << Q03 << "; Q(1,3) = " << Q13 << "; Q(2,3) = " << Q23 << "; Q(3,2) = " << Q32 << "; Q(3,3) = " << Q33 << ";" << std::endl;


    Mat map11, map12, map21, map22;
    initUndistortRectifyMap(CameraMatrix1, disCoeffs1, R1, P1, imgLeft.size(), CV_32FC1, map11, map12);
    initUndistortRectifyMap(CameraMatrix2, disCoeffs2, R2, P2, imgRight.size(), CV_32FC1, map21, map22);

    Mat img1r, img2r;
    remap(imgLeft, img1r, map11, map12, INTER_LINEAR);
    remap(imgRight, img2r, map21, map22, INTER_LINEAR);

    imgLeft = img1r;
    imgRight = img2r;

    Mat disp, disp8;
    char* method = "BM";
    if (!(strcmp(method, "BM")))
    {
        StereoBM sbm;
        sbm.state->SADWindowSize = 25;
        sbm.state->numberOfDisparities = 112; //64; //112
        sbm.state->preFilterSize = 5;
        sbm.state->preFilterCap = 61;
        sbm.state->minDisparity = -39;
        sbm.state->textureThreshold = 150; //507
        sbm.state->uniquenessRatio = 0;
        sbm.state->speckleWindowSize = 0;
        sbm.state->speckleRange = 8;
        sbm.state->disp12MaxDiff = 1;
        sbm(imgLeft, imgRight, disp);
    }
    else if (!(strcmp(method, "SGBM")))
    {
        StereoSGBM sbm;
        sbm.SADWindowSize = 25;
        sbm.numberOfDisparities = 64; //144
        sbm.preFilterCap = 63;
        sbm.minDisparity = -10; //-39;
        sbm.uniquenessRatio = 10;
        sbm.speckleWindowSize = 100;
        sbm.speckleRange = 32;
        sbm.disp12MaxDiff = 1;
        sbm.fullDP = false;
        sbm.P1 = 216;
        sbm.P2 = 864;
        sbm(imgLeft, imgRight, disp);
    }

    //normalize(disp, disp8, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8U);
    normalize(disp, disp8, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
    // Check its extreme values
    double minVal; double maxVal;

    minMaxLoc(disp, &minVal, &maxVal);

    printf("Min disp: %f Max value: %f \n", minVal, maxVal);

    // Display it as a CV_8UC1 image
    disp.convertTo(disp8, CV_8UC1, 255 / (maxVal - minVal));

    cv::Mat recons3D(disp8.size(), CV_32F);

    //Reproject image to 3D
    std::cout << "Reprojecting image to 3D..." << std::endl;
    cv::reprojectImageTo3D(disp8, recons3D, Q, false, CV_32F);



    waitKey(1);



    //Create point cloud and fill it
    std::cout << "Creating Point Cloud..." << std::endl;
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr point_cloud_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

    double px, py, pz;
    uchar pr, pg, pb;

    for (int i = 0; i < imgLeft.rows; i++)
    {
        uchar* rgb_ptr = imgLeft.ptr<uchar>(i);
#ifdef CUSTOM_REPROJECT
        uchar* disp_ptr = disp8.ptr<uchar>(i);
#else
        float* recons_ptr = recons3D.ptr<float>(i);
#endif
        for (int j = 0; j < imgRight.cols; j++)
        {
            //Get 3D coordinates
#ifdef CUSTOM_REPROJECT
            uchar d = disp_ptr[j];
            if (d == 0) continue; //Discard bad pixels
            double pw = -1.0 * static_cast<double>(d)* Q32 + Q33;
            px = static_cast<double>(j)+Q03;
            py = static_cast<double>(i)+Q13;
            pz = Q23;

            px = px / pw;
            py = py / pw;
            pz = pz / pw;

    #else
            px = recons_ptr[3 * j];
            py = recons_ptr[3 * j + 1];
            pz = recons_ptr[3 * j + 2];
    #endif

            //Get RGB info
            pb = rgb_ptr[3 * j];
            pg = rgb_ptr[3 * j + 1];
            pr = rgb_ptr[3 * j + 2];

            //Insert info into point cloud structure
            pcl::PointXYZRGB point;
            point.x = px;
            point.y = py;
            point.z = pz;
            uint32_t rgb = (static_cast<uint32_t>(pr) << 16 |
                static_cast<uint32_t>(pg) << 8 | static_cast<uint32_t>(pb)); //NULL
            point.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
            point_cloud_ptr->points.push_back(point);
        }
    }
    point_cloud_ptr->width = (int)point_cloud_ptr->points.size();
    point_cloud_ptr->height = 20; //1


    //Create visualizer
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer;
    viewer = createVisualizer(point_cloud_ptr);

    //Main loop
    while (!viewer->wasStopped())
    {
        viewer->spinOnce(10); //100
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(100000));
    }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't tell about you problem, but if you need to show images, you can post a public link to them, e.g. imgur

Comment: @Miki. 
Thank's for the comment I will edit the post and post some public links with images soon ! :)